# when to use the prototype js framework

Tags: jquery, prototypejs

I post this post not to make a comparsion between prototype and jquery,I just want to get some suggestions.

In our application we want to provide a base javascript lib for other people use. So we may have to create some classes,may use the extend/create functions.

However the jquery is so wonderful when do some operation with the dom element,so I want to know when to use the prototype and when to use jquery?

In our project,which is better? Since we do not use them both at the same time,the prototype seems do not play nice with other js libs.

Comment: mootools/prototype/jquery all have their pluses and minuses. If one works fine for you, stick with it, otherwise... don't. There's no real way to answer this question, so voting to close.

Comment: Depends on your project. If you don't work with the DOM it might be even better to use not library at all to reduce dependencies...

Comment: This is pretty subjective. Both tools have their advtanges and disadvantages, so it's really down to personal preference. You say that Prototype doesn't work well with your other JS libs, so maybe you've answered your question there?

Comment: Yes,I do not try to start a debat. I just post my requirements and look for a suggestion. Since we want to build a API,so the OO operation is necessary,in this point,the prototype is better,but we also need the dom operation which I think jquery is best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They both provide the same functionality more or less, I personally prefer jQuery for having a more "logical" interface and very easy to extend.

check http://blog.jeremymartin.name/2008/02/building-your-first-jquery-plugin-that.html to see how to write plugins.